# Is this correct syntax for a C# statment

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is this the correct syntax for a C statment. I recieve the following error message in Visual Studios when trying to use it.

```
intResult = Convert.ToInt32(cmdSelect.Parameters("RETURN_VALUE").Value);
```

```
non-invocable memeber of System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.Parameters can not be used as a method.
```

Can anyone help clear this up.

I am using the following namespaces as well

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Security;
```

Comment: I guess that Parameters isn't a method but has an indexer. So you need to use `cmdSelect.Parameters["RETURN_VALUE"]`

Comment: 5 people battling it out for the accept.  All within a minute of each other, all with the right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, indexers use square brackets, not parentheses as in VB.NET. This should do the trick:

```
intResult = Convert.ToInt32(cmdSelect.Parameters["RETURN_VALUE"].Value);
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to use an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), not call a function, so you should use square brackets:

```
intResult = Convert.ToInt32(cmdSelect.Parameters["RETURN_VALUE"].Value);
```

Answer (score 4):

Should be:

```
intResult = Convert.ToInt32(cmdSelect.Parameters["RETURN_VALUE"].Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [] index operators on Parameters instead of parentheses:

```
intResult = Convert.ToInt32(cmdSelect.Parameters["RETURN_VALUE"].Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cmdSelect.Parameters["RETURN_VALUE"].Value
```

indexors are [] in c#, in VB.net they are ()